# Confused with two zlib1.dll of SDL_image extension and SDL_ttf?

Tags: dll, sdl, codeblocks

Inside the SDL_image extension bin folder there is a file zlib1.dll and inside the SDL_ttf bin folder there is also zlib1.dll file,are these two files the same or different because when i tried to copy all the files under bin of SDL_ttf  to widows/system32 it says "replace" or "skip this file" ,i have already install SDL_image extension and using it with code blocks 13.12.What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

The files should be the same (differing only in when the were compiled) so you can safely replace one of them. Both libraries use and therefore include the zlib1.dll as they are independent from each other, but when you use both this happens.